# Unable to display product images in magento frontend

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I wrote small module to filter custom products and display it on frontend. I'm getting success in displaying products but magento is unable to load our product images. But when I refresh the page I get success is getting few images. Here is the URL for your consideration: [https://bombaytrooper.com/magic-search?design=+Hungry+Gym+Gaming&gender=63](https://bombaytrooper.com/magic-search?design=%20Hungry%20Gym%20Gaming&gender=63)

Here is the code to get product attributes

```
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('product_url');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('id');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('priceHtml');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('review_summary_Html');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('add_to_cart_url');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('add_url');
```

Is there something wrong with my script or something wrong with magento's cache?
Is there any way to get all product images?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Images are loading fine for me at the linked URL. Perhaps you need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Yes the images are loading fine as Ben Edwards mention .